# Simple java method getIntBetweenBounds gives NullPointerException error

Tags: java, arrays, int, bounds

I'm making a simple method for a Java game with a class called `DealOrNoDeal`.
It's a very simple method to get a int input from user between two bounds. But for some reason it thrown a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class DealOrNoDeal {
    public Scanner scanner;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DealOrNoDeal().run();
    }
    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] values = {1, 20, 100, 1000, 2000, 5000};

        System.out.println("Please select  the suitcase that you would like to keep (1-6): ");
        int keuze = getIntBetweenBounds(1, 6);
    }
    private int getIntBetweenBounds(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
        int result = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please select  the suitcase that you would like to keep (1-6): ");
        while (result < lowerBound || result > upperBound) {
            System.out.println("Please select  the suitcase that you would like to keep (1-6): ");
            result = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        return result; 
    }
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean by stack trace?

Comment: How about if you change `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` by `this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: @LoekRomer Stack trace is your returned full exception

Comment: @rafa thanx! It works now!

Answer (score 1):

You re-declare the `Scanner` in this line:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Remove the `Scanner` and your code should work:

```java
scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The null pointer is due to the fact that the first `Scanner` (the instance variable) is not initialized. You created a local variable called `scanner` that was named the same as the instance variable called `scanner`.

Comment: No need to post as a comment. This is a valid answer.